# IE11 shows page source instead of content when using the jump list

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

When I open a web page by using the Windows 8.1 jump list...

[image: jump list]

...the page is downloaded to a local temporary directory and the page source is shown instead of the rendered page content:

[image: page source]

This only happens when I use the jump list, not when I manually type in the URL. Opening a page via Favorites/History also works fine.

What happened? How can I fix it? I upgraded Windows 8.1 to [Update 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/en-us) a few days ago (which also updated IE from 11.0.5 to 11.0.7), so that *might* be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in [KB2919355 (Windows 8.1 Update 1)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/en-us): After uninstalling KB2919355, the problem disappeared. IE 11 reverted from 11.0.7 back to 11.0.5 and jump lists worked again.

Update: This bug seems to be fixed with KB2938439 (also included on the download page linked above). Installing KB2938439 after KB2919355 fixes the issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the URL, it appears that you are not going to a webserver, but opening a local file. The browser gets a hint about how to display the resource based on a few ways: the content-type sent by the webserver in response header for the request and lacking a webserver (as in this case), the file extension.

If you save a web page to your disk, and rename it from .html to .txt, opening it in a browser will display it as raw text file instead of a rendered html file.

If your URL doesn't end with a non .html extension, perhaps it's getting an older cached value from your browser's temporary storage. Try cleaning the browser's cache to force the jump list to get a fresh non-cached copy.

Comment: Unfortunately, cleaning the browser's cache didn't work. It *does* get a fresh copy of the page: After clicking on a jump list link, one can (very briefly) see a download window as the HTML page is downloaded to the local directory.